# How to use OR operator in dialogflow fulfillment

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have a list of 4 phone's and I am using OR operator but it is not working properly

this is my code

```
app.intent(SHOW_PHONE_INTENT, (conv) => {
  conv.contexts.set(AppContexts.AWAITING_PHONE, 1);
  conv.ask("Here's the list of phone's.");
  conv.ask(new List(PhoneList));
});

app.intent(SELECTED_PHONE_INTENT, (conv, input, option) => {
    const context = conv.contexts.get(AppContexts.AWAITING_PHONE);
    conv.contexts.set(AppContexts1.AWAITING_REPLY, 1, {phone: option});

    if (option === 'Phone1' || 'Phone2'){
      conv.ask(`${option} is in stock. Do you want to add it to your cart.`); 
    } else if (option === 'Phone3'){
      conv.ask(`${option} is out of stock. Would you like to order other products`);
    } else if (option === 'Phone4'){
      conv.ask(`${option} will be launched 1 week later. Would you like to register for this`);
    }
});
```

but when I select Phone4 or Phone3 then also it is returning response of option1

```
conv.ask(`${option} is in stock. Do you want to add it to your cart.`);
```

Am I doing something wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please change the conditional statement to this .

```
if (option === 'Phone1' || option === 'Phone2')
```